# Filtering speed of vehicle

Tags: java, algorithm, filtering, signal-processing

I have android application that collects information about vehicle speed approximately every 200ms and then sends them on server. On server i will show speed graph and also calculate travelled distance. Lot of these speed records are same or redundant so i would like to filter them out without too much affecting calculated distance. Is there any algorithm for filtering those data?

Comment: Why do you want to filter them out? Are they noisy? If you want to filter out just because they are similar, you are looking for a compression algorithm. If you want actually to 'compress' them in a graph, so the user only sees big changes in speed, you could try a moving average; when speed deviates more than "n" standard deviations from moving average, you plot a point in the graph.

Comment: Thanks for help. I found about compression algorithm called Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm (RDP) that do exactly what i wanted.